# jquery draggable options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i want the draggable object to revert back to its original position when i click a button.
i used 'destroy' option but it doesnt seem to work. it disables the dragging but doesnt revert back to original position.

can someone help?

EDIT PART:

```
$('#Zoom').toggle(function() {
                $("#draggable").draggable({});},
            function() {
                $("#draggable").draggable('destroy');});
```

this is a toggle button that i am using to enable dragging. the destroy option only disables dragging and does not revert the object back to the original position.

**also this is the button i want to make the object come back to its original position:**

```
nextImg.addEventListener('click', function() {img.setAttribute("src", "img"+(++imgnum)+".jpg");}, false);
```

Comment: is this after you've dragged it to a new location?  after you've dropped it somewhere?  mid drag?

Comment: after i have dragged the object to a new position. when i click a button it should revert back to its original position.

Comment: @amit - You should put a bounty on this, you have 100 reps, that should do it

Comment: @karim: how do i do it. i dont see any option for bounty?

Comment: From the faq: "If, after two days, you still don't have an answer you like, you can offer a bounty."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#draggable").data("Left", $("#draggable").position().left)
                    .data("Top", $("#draggable").position().top);
    $("#draggable").draggable();

    $("#nextImg").bind('click', function() {
        $("#draggable").animate(
            { "left": $("#draggable").data("Left"), 
                "top": $("#draggable").data("Top")
            }, "slow");
        $("#draggable").attr("src", "img"+(++imgnum)+".jpg");
    });
});
</script>
```

I've made some assumptions, such as the nextImg object having an id of "nextImg" so that I can bind the click event using jQuery (one less step in the javascript event binding process?)  I'm also assuming that you don't really want to destroy the drag functionality.

Comment: i do want to destroy the draggable property. thats fine i am going to test this right now. lets see how it works out. thanks a lot for the effort! A big thumbs up!

Comment: SUPER. one part of the script is working. the image resets back to the original position. but it does not switch to the next image. let me look into it. thanks a lot.

Comment: I like the use of data, I don't use that feature enough. Good work.

Answer (score 4):

Revert executes when dragging has stopped (with optional delay), not on click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var originalTop = $('#draggable').position().top;
   var originalLeft = $('#draggable').position().left;

   $('#Zoom').toggle(
         function() {
            $("#draggable").draggable({});},
         function() {
            $("#draggable").draggable('destroy');
            $('#draggable').position().top = originalTop;
            $('#draggable').position().left= originalLeft;
         });
});
```

Comment: This could be made more concise by just caching the original position object, but I figured this illustrated the point more verbosely

Comment: i think this might work. one problem i am having is that thingtodrag and #thingtoclick have different eventlistner functions. #thinktoclick doesnt recognize the originalTop and originalLeft variables. forgive me im fairly new to this.

Comment: pls see my Edit in the original post.

Comment: Edited to reflect your code, I believe this is what you are looking for

Comment: jQuery's position() method is only a getter, not a setter; thus the last two lines of code won't actually change #draggable's position.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I'm pretty sure this will do the trick:

```
//reposition the draggable after it has finished
$(".selector").draggable({  
    stop: function(e,ui) { 
        ui.instance.element.css("left","0px"); 
        ui.instance.element.css("top","0px"); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: wouldnt revert immediately revert the dragged object to its original position? i want it to happen when i click a button.

Comment: yes i tried just that. it disables the dragging but does not bring the object back to its original position. what i want to achieve is: in an image slideshow, when usr is done dragging an image, when the user clicks on next image button, the next image should display at the original position.

Comment: @amit - see my edit again please. Also, feel free to buy me a beer if it works.

Comment: i am going to testdrive it right now. but wouldnt it reset the object to 0,0 of the document? i hope it resets the object to the 0,0 of the container. i owe u more than a beer. u hv been a lifesaver since yesterday.

Comment: @amit - dammit, I'm all out of ideas & inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

```
function revertable($drag){     
    $drag.data({ top: $drag.css('top'), left: $drag.css('left') })  
    $('.'+$drag.attr('id')+'.revert').data({ revert: '#'+$drag.attr('id') })
        .on('click',function(){
            var $rev = $( $(this).data('revert') );
            $rev.css({ top: $rev.data('top'), left: $rev.data('left') });
    })
}
```

// simply call the function in the create event

```
var $drag = $('#my_draggable'); //your element
$drag.draggable({
    create: revertable($drag)
});
```

//test it: change the top/left values, refresh, click the button to see it work.

```
<div id="my_draggable" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px">
    Drag Me Around
</div>

<button class="my_draggable revert">Revert My Draggable</button>
```

...tested, should work for any element
(requires jquery 1.7 for .on() function)

Answer (score -1):

Would revert help you out?

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-revert

Comment: Revert returns the element to its original position when dragging stops, not when the user clicks a button.

Answer (score -1):

Revert option is set to false by default, you've to set it to true.

```
$("#draggable").draggable({ 
    revert: true
});
```

this should do it actually...

Comment: i know that. i explicitly remember to have set it to true.