# div draggable not working after reset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have 4 divs on my page, say div1, div2,div3,div4 which are draggable.

```
$("#div1").draggable();
$("#div2").draggable();
$("#div3").draggable();
$("#div4").draggable();
```

First time when the page loads, I have captured positions of all divs' like mentioned below.

```
div1Position = $("#div1").position();
div2Position = $("#div2").position();
div3Position = $("#div3").position();
div3Position = $("#div4").position();
```

I have a reset button on my page. On the click of this button, I'm reseting the positions of all divs to their original position.

```
$("#div1").css({ top: div1Position.top, left: div1Position.left, position: 'initial' });
$("#div2").css({ top: div2Position.top, left: div2Position.left, position: 'initial' });
$("#div3").css({ top: div3Position.top, left: div3Position.left, position: 'initial' });
$("#div4").css({ top: div4Position.top, left: div4Position.left, position: 'initial' });
```

Till here it is working fine. But after reset , all the divs are no more draggable.Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: can you remove the `position: 'initial'` while reseting and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to set the div as draggable again on reset button click.

```
$("#div1").draggable();
$("#div2").draggable();
$("#div3").draggable();
$("#div4").draggable();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040902/jquery-draggable-options

Similar thread